# Service mesh with consul and docker swarm EE

Tags: docker, service, consul, swarm, mesh-network

I'm new in service mesh with Consul.

I found a lot of documentation about using Consul and Envoy for service mesh in K8S but I'm not finding much documentation about using it on docker swarm (Enterprise Edition).

My question is: is it possible to implement it on Docker Swarm EE? If not, what are the technical reasons that prevent or not recommend to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same.
The main problem with docker swarm it seems is it lacks the concept of "sidecar" containers. For example, k8's has "pods". I haven't used k8's, but my understanding is that, you can group services into a unit called a "pod". This has benefits and really enables the mesh style architecture.. one reason is that services in the same "pod" can all communicate through "localhost" on different port bindings - i.e the services are "local" to eachother. When you want a "companion" service this is what you need as you know communicating with it is going to be fast as it is essentially local / co located with your app. Now consider swarm. You can add services to your stack, but you don't necessarily know where they are going to be placed - your "side car proxy" servcice could end up being placed on node 2 whilst your app is on node 1. This is not very efficient as it means there are now network hops to route traffic between your app and its "sidecar" proxy which could be on the other side of the data centre, but should really be local. So you start thinking of creative workarounds.. What about if I use "placement" settings to place my service and the sidecar service on the same node? Well then you lose the ability for swarm to place them on a different node if that node goes down, because your placement options have confined it to only one node. What if.. you deploy the "sidecar" proxy as a "global" service so that it is available on each node? Then your apps should all be able to communicate with the service via the IP address of whatever node its on.. but how do you configure that IP address per task (container)? I'm exploring that option, but then that gives you a single sidecar instance per node (1 instance to potentially serve many services) so this has impacts for how you scale that sidecar. I think possibly one other solution is that you have to embed these "sidecar" services into your own service docker image so that they are truly running locally with your app. However I haven't seen any that really advocate that approach so it's most likely fraught with hurdles to overcome. Most documentation is for k8s,, and nothing for swarm for these sorts of reasons. If only swarm could have added this ability in it's style of simplicity it would extend its reach so much.